# How to run unit testing tests from command line?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, command-line

I googled and found the below helpful references. Currently I want to run all from the command-line (for easy of execution & quickness) in cases:

1. A specific test (ie. a test written by a method marked [TestMethod()])
2. All tests in a class
3. All impacted tests of the current TFS pending change of mine.
4. All tests
5. All tests except the ones marked as category [TestCategory("some-category")]

I'm not sure how can I write a correct command for my needs above.

References:

1. the MSTest.exe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182487.aspx
2. the MSTest.exe's detailed options http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx
3. obtaining the result http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182488.aspx

### [Edit]

After a while, I found the below useful tips.

1. run Visual Studio unit tests by using MSTest.exe, located at `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe` in my case.
2. using `/testcontainer:Path\To\Your\TestProjectAssembly.dll` to indicate where your tests are coded. You can specify multiple '/testcontainer' options if required.
3. using `/test:TestFilter` to filter the tests to run. Note that this filter is applied to the full test method name (ie. FullNamespace.Classname.MethodName)

Comment: This is invaluable - I was getting an 'out of memory' exception when running from within Visual Studio 2010 due to some relatively memory hungry test code (using about 300MB or so of heap memory). Running from the command line solved my issues.

Comment: I just get "no tests to execute". I guess this doesn't work for visual studio 2019

Answer (score 18):

Currently I can have some answers for my needs:

1. **A specific test** (ie. a test written by a method marked `[TestMethod()]`)
   Use `MSTest.exe` `/container:`*TheAssemblyContainingYourSpecificTest* `/test:`*TheSpecificTestName*
2. **All tests in a class**
   Use `MSTest.exe` `/container:`*TheAssemblyContainingYourClass* `/test:`*TheClassNameWithFullNamespace*
   Note that the `/test:` is the filter which uses the full name of the class when filtering.

The others are still left unknown. Please disscuss if you know how.

Comment: /container doesn't work for me, however /testcontainer works

Answer (score 15):

For number **4.** To run all tests in an assembly it's simply:

mstest /testcontainer:YourCompiledTestAssembly.dll

Comment: Do you know if this can also contain wildcards, for tests that are spread out over multiple assemblies.
(I'm trying to create a clean batch file for my OpenCover tests)

Comment: @RobertSirre, for multiple assemblies see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961633/how-to-run-all-tests-in-my-solution-using-command-line-mstest-exe

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim, a real clean solution is not given there (I prefer not to use Gallio, adding even more software), nor the vsmdi file, which is deprecated. Later I found out that MSTest accepts specifying /testcontainer multiple times.

Answer (score 5):

For question

> 5 All tests except the ones marked as category
>   [TestCategory("some-category")]

Use

```
mstest.exe /testcontainer:yourTests.dll  /category:"!some-category"
```

If you need to exclude more than one category, use

```
mstest.exe /testcontainer:yourTests.dll  /category:"!group1&!group2"
```

Reference:  [/category filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489%28v=VS.110%29.aspx#category)

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested by the [**Gallio**](http://gallio.org) bundle. It provides a free common automation platform to run your tests (MSTest, MbUnit, NUnit, xUnit, etc.) with various test runners (GUI, command line, PoSh, plugins for 3rd party tools, etc.)

In particular you may want to use **[Gallio.Echo](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=tools:echo)** which is a nice command line test runner:

[image: Gallio.Echo]

The Gallio test runners have also [filtering capabilities](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=tools:filter_arguments_for_echo) to run a subset of your unit tests only (e.g. per category, per fixture, etc.)

Comment: Except if you are using Nunit or MsUnit tests filtering on category is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

** adding this due to errors I've encountered.
To run all just use '''vstest.console.exe .\x64\Release\UnitTesting.dll'''
vstest.console.exe is not deprecated so you will not need the /nologo suppression.

If needed it also has --TestCaseFilter|/TestCaseFilter: