# How to run ALL tests in my solution using command line MSTest.exe?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, command-line

According to MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182487.aspx) and discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930445/how-to-run-unit-testing-tests-from-command-line), we can use `MSTest.exe` to run tests from command line - which is sweet and faster than running within the IDE (especially slow if you are working on a big solution like me).

My question is how can I use `MSTest.exe` to run **all** tests in my **solution**? The command only have the `/test` option to filter the tests in **one** assembly specified in `/container` option. I only can think of calling this command N times given that I can have all the N test assembly in my solution (!?) Moreover, the results after run are per-assembly basics so that it's not easy to get what tests were failed/passed.

If you know a better way, please share! Thank you!

Comment: You could also use ILMerge to merge the assemblies prior to executing your tests.

Answer (score 13):

I accomplished this using the `testmetadata` argument and pointing it to my .vsmdi file.

As explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489(v=VS.110).aspx#testmetadata).

E.g.:

```
mstest /testmetadata:mySolution.vsmdi
```

However note that `testmetadata` can be more fragile (e.g. [empty test lists combined with the Ignore attribute cause "Specified cast is not valid"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vstsprofiler/thread/e466550e-475f-4c0f-8225-26147cc3918c/)). 
Creating a batch with all DLLs containing test classes could be more reliable alternative.

Comment: Hi. The test editor is deprecated in VS2015. Do you know how can I migrate the list to the new functionality of playlists in VS2015?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

I needed the same thing, without wanting to install anything or generate `vsmdi` files, so I came up with this `PowerShell` script, below. It runs **ALL** tests in **one** command on a **folder** and it's subfolders (not **solution**, but fine for me).

*Feel free to suggest how to make this script more elegant:*

```
$x = ""; dir *\bin\*test*.dll -Recurse | foreach { $x += "/testcontainer:""$_"" " }; iex "mstest $x"
```

**Instructions:**

- Add path to `mstest.exe` via `Environment variables` variable `PATH`, otherwise just replace `mstest` with its full path in the `PowerShell` script above.

  [image]
- Open `PowerShell`, paste the command.
- Modify `*\bin\*test*.dll` to meet your needs. In current script it will get all `DLLs` in the `bin` folder recursively, containing substring "test" in the filename.
- Run the command!

Comment: I have modified it a bit to be able to find test dll better: `$x = ""; Get-ChildItem -path . -Recurse -Include *Test.dll | where { $_.FullName -match "bin" }  | foreach { $x += "/testcontainer:""$_"" " }; iex "mstest $x"`

Answer (score 5):

You might want to have a look at the [**Gallio.Echo**](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=tools:echo) test runner which comes with the [**Gallio**](http://gallio.org) test automation platform. It's a free (OSS) package with many convenient reporting tools and test runners and which supports most the existing test frameworks (MbUnit, NUnit, MSTest, xUnit, etc.)

[image]

More specifically, [Gallio.Echo](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=tools:echo) is a versatile command line test runner. You can specify a list of test assemblies, various filters, and many extra options. Gallio consolidates the test results in a single report (Xml, Html, Zip, etc.)

Answer (score -3):

Just use:

```
mstest.exe /testcontainer:yourTests.dll /resultsfile:res.trx
```

and it will run all tests in that assembly, and spit out the results in the specified file.

Comment: The question was about running all the tests, like vs does when click Run>All tests in solution