# Execute Unit Tests using MsBuild command line

Tags: c#, unit-testing, scripting, command-line, msbuild

I use scripting for this:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" 
  get $/DmlOnDemmand /recursive /force /noprompt
```

And I build solution .sln

```
call %msBuildDir%\msbuild %solutionName% /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=%buildType%
```

Now, I would like execute all Unit Tests and check all is OK.

How can I execute unit tests of .csproj projects of a solution from the command line using a build tool like MSBuild?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run unit testing tests from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930445/how-to-run-unit-testing-tests-from-command-line)

Answer (score 10):

Look at `VSTest.Console.EXE` they added this for CodedUI tests. Seems to have more functionality. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155800.aspx
in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow` directory.

Answer (score 3):

I inserted a Test-Project in the Solution.

Every build a library the test depends on is changed the solution updates the Test-Project. The Test is automaticaly run after each "Test-Project" change with the Post-Build option.

The result from the Test is directly shown in the buildlog.

Comment: @Kiquenet You build the project as usual because of the "Post-Build" the test runs automaticaly