# How we can automatically run the test methods in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to  run all the test methods once at a time automatically.
I have separate test methods written in separate files.
Is there any way to run all the test methods at a time automatically.
Please suggest if any.

Comment: You can launch it in command line.
Look at this thread


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996392/execute-unit-tests-using-msbuild-command-line

Comment: By the way what do you mean by automatically ? I am using Jenkins and msbuild in command line. Each time I commit the tests are launched.

Answer (score 4):

Continuous Tests:  http://continuoustests.com/ is a free automated test runner that supports the .NET and Mono platforms.    I don't think it has a command line version.

Gallio http://www.gallio.org/  has a command line runner and a GUI runner (Icarus).  I use it but I am not sure if it will do automated or continuous test runs

NCrunch http://www.ncrunch.net/  is also an automated test runner that works in Visual Studio.  It used to be free but is now payware.

Answer (score 1):

IF you are using NUnit you can use the NUnit GUI. Another option that is mostly framework agnostic is [TestDriven.Net](http://testdriven.net/).