# How can I programmatically get information about or manipulate another solution? (Visual Studio, C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've managed to write code which can clean and build another solution, and run all the MSTests (and maybe others such as NUnit) from the solution, but I need to be able to get all the test class and method names in order to run the tests individually (or I could extract the names of the passed/failed tests from the output string when they are run all at once - but that's not very dependable long-term).

I'm feeling like this should all be a separate program/plugin which I can then use how I need to in my project - but surely someone's already written something like this?

I'm imagining I'd be able to do something like:

```
var solution = new Solution("C:\Documents\VisualStudioFolder\MySolution.sln");
solution.Clean();
solution.Build(); // could return a bool to check it was successful
List<Test> tests = solution.GetTests();
foreach (Test test in tests) {
    if (test.Run()) {
        Console.WriteLine("Test passed");
    }
}
```

Does this kind of thing exist??

Comment: I would recommend you to use MSBuild and MSTest may by using Process.Start.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996392/execute-unit-tests-using-msbuild-command-line

Comment: Yes, that's how I'm doing it at the moment and it's fine for building it, but for running the tests it doesn't give any kind of break down of results (unless I extract them from the output string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do was write a Visual Studio package (a plugin), within which you can access the currently opened solution:

```
var solution = ((DTE) GetService(typeof (DTE))).Solution;
```

and then:

```
var buildObject = solution.SolutionBuild;
buildObject.Build(true); // saves and builds
if (buildObject.LastBuildInfo == 0) {
    //then build was successful
}
```

I still haven't found a good way of running the tests, but hopefully this bit might help someone in future.