# How to customize MSTest.exe?

Tags: c#, mstest

I have a class and methods inside it written in C#. I want to run all those methods that are marked by a specific attribute (TestMethod attribute). How do I run them using MSTest?

**Note**: I want to do it in command line, and not in Visual Studio

Comment: By a specific attribute, are you using the standard [TestMethod] attribute to denote these tests?

Comment: Yes. I am using the [TestMethod] attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSTest.exe Command-Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
[How to: Run Tests from the Command Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182487%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: @Koshimitsu : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930445/how-to-run-unit-testing-tests-from-command-line