# BAT file to build solution and execute Unit test

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create bat file which will build solution and execute Unit test cases in .Net

Has anyone done anything similar, or have any comments?

Answer (score 1):

Info about the command line args for building a solution is available here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(v=vs.80).aspx

Your command for building will be something along the lines of:

"C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "SolutionName.sln" /build Release

For running your Unit Tests if they are MSTests then you will want to use MSTest.exe which is available in the same folder as the devenv.exe. Command Line options for MSTest are available here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check if this post [How to run unit testing tests from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930445/how-to-run-unit-testing-tests-from-command-line) is useful. Currently, using devenv.exe and mstest.exe seems easy with command line help. You can try.
`MSTest /help`
or
`devenv /help`
in Developer Command Prompt.