# Jenkins Plugin MSTestRunner equivalent in GitHub Workflow Actions

Tags: msbuild, yaml, jenkins-plugins, mstest, github-actions

Is there an MSTest.exe YAML equivalent in Github Actions Workflow?
If there is can a get sample yaml that includes how a `/testcontainer`, `/category`, and `/resultsfile` would look like?

I was able to find [MSBuild](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-msbuild). Not sure if it's possible to use MsBuild to run MSTest's if it is then an example using the above would solve my question as well.

Current Workflow yaml

```yaml
 name: MS Test Build

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:

  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
                             
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Setup MSBuild
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2

    - name: MSTest
      shell: powershell
      run: '& "$(vswhere -property installationPath)\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:Test.dll /resultsfile:TestResults.trx'
```

edit: updated with semi-working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution. Still looking for improvements but this will work

```yaml
name: MS Test Build

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:

  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
                             
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Setup MSBuild
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2

    - name: MSTest
      shell: powershell
      run: '& "$(vswhere -property installationPath)\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:Test.dll /resultsfile:TestResults.trx'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have msbuild at hand you should also be able to run mstest:

```yaml
name: MSBuild and MSTest CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Dependency - MSBuild
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2
      with:
        vswhere-path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer'  

    - name: MSBuild
      working-directory: src
      continue-on-error: true
      run: msbuild MyProject.csproj

    - name: MSTest
      working-directory: src
      continue-on-error: true
      run: mstest <paramaters here>
```

[Here you have info how to use msttest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930445/how-to-run-unit-testing-tests-from-command-line)

Comment: I do not need the use MSBuild. I tried the code provided but I don't have a .csproj from the Jenins plugin. It also doesn't recognize `mstest`

Comment: How did you use `microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2` with `vswhere-path`? or not? I tried with `vswhere-path` and then I was able to use mstest. With above example I'm not saying that you need csproj file. This was an example.

Comment: I updated my q with the yaml that is currently working and what I what the output should look like. If you have an optimized version that can help as well.